# Hiding an element with on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my problem,

I would like to hide the div element tagged by the ID 'professinoal-panel' using the jQuery on click event.  I thought it was simple but I am new to jQuery and having a bit of difficulty with the syntax.

```js
  $("#hideButton").on("click", function(e){
        $('#professional-panel').fadeOut('fast');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <span class="fa fa-file-word-o pull-left"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o pull-left"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-print custom-print pull-left"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-envelope-o custom-print pull-left"></span>
                        <input type="button" id="hideButton" value="hide" />
           </div>

    <div id="professional-panel">

                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-collaboratorb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-creatorb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-investigatorb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-testerb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-influencerb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="photo">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="../images/problem-solving-decision-makerb.jpg" alt="Expert" class="profile-image">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: may be u haven't inserted the jquery library

Comment: your code is working .What the  problem https://jsfiddle.net/wy0uc4gn/.  I think jquery library is the problem

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Everything seems to work fine here.

Comment: The problem is that I click on the button but nothing happens. the div with the ID professional-panel is suppose to disappear

Comment: The code I inserted in the js sheet which contains a great deal of other code exists. I am wondering if I am not placeing it correctly within the other code?

Comment: it does disappers it working properly. Check if you have properly include jQuery in your page.

Comment: Your code is working, i think you have to change jquery version please that version to 1.7 or greater than that, and please check syntax in browser console. $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#hideButton").on("click",function(e){
  $('#professional-panel').fadeOut('slow');
 });
})

Comment: I have embedded this into a sheet where a great deal of other code exists for this page and works fine. I am sure it is not a missing jQuery on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem just recently, and for me the solution was to insert the click function inside **document.ready**.

So for your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hideButton").on("click", function(e){
      $('#professional-panel').fadeOut('fast');
   });
});
```

This is just to make sure the page has successfully loaded the code and got it ready for execution. As others state in the comments section, the snippet of your code seems to be working just perfectly, that's why I would try the document.ready.

If this does not work, and you're absolutely positive on that jQuery is being loaded in your page, let me figure something else out. :)

Comment: It is not working :(   This must have something to do with the way I am positioning the code on the page which has 200 other lines of code.  I tried putting it in the code as well as starting at the end. Both don't work.

Comment: Next thing I would've recommended is to put the code in the very beginning of your JavaScript in order to make sure it does not cut on the way there, but it's good you already tried it. A Single missing quote or other character can break up the code and prevent everything below it from being driven. By the way, I am not sure if you need the "e" inside your on("click") function, not sure if it causes problems, but it surely wont be necessary.

Comment: Do these work for you: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: I put it at the very beginning (even before the other set of code). It still doenst work